# I am not sure which NoSQL is suitable for my scenario

Tags: cassandra, redis, couchbase, iot, nosql

I am trying to design create a cloud based system (IaaS) that will gather data from sensors (water pollution related activity) and upon certain events will decide to process the data for a specific sensor. 
Data characteristics are:
1. For each sensor data is being sent once every couple of days (up to 6 times a month)
2. each sensor reading contains about 5000 events that are encapsulated in 50-100 messages that are sent to the server (such "session" takes about 20 minutes where messages are sent every 5 seconds)
3. I am building the system to handle rate of 30,000 messages per second.
4. processing of the data shouldn't be real time , I have about 10 minutes once the "session" is finished to do the processing.
5. 90% of the sessions are not interesting and can be thrown away once they are finished. the other 10% have event or event encapsulated in the messages that according to them I need to decide if I need to process the entire session data and send an alert to the sensor that there is a pollution.

I created a tool that generates 5000 messages per second and I am trying to figure out which database would be the most optimal for my scenario.
These are the databases I am thinking to try:

1. Cassandra - I will save for each session an in memory collection of keys. the keys are for the messages that are stored in cassandra. Once I detect a message that contains bad readings I will need to pull all of the other messages in the "session" and process them (that means 50-100 requests to cassandra). My concern here is about write performance (since I have many read and write operations) + I don't have a good strategy for deleting the 90% not needed sessions.
2. Couchbase - I will save a document for each "session" according to sensorID and will append each message to the document. Once I detect a message that contains bad readings I will only need to send one request for the document. My concern here is about the read performance.
3. Redis - use it like cassandra. I assume performance will be the best but I will need to handle the sharding and replication of data myself in order not to reach the memory limit

I would love to hear which option would be the most appropriate

thanks

Comment: Couchbase has great read performance (I think it outperforms Cassandra), see http://blog.couchbase.com/dissecting-nosql-benchmark

Answer (score 2):

Reg. Redis – You may consider using a DAAS (Data as a Service). The service will manage for you all the instances, clusters, scaling, data persistence and high availability settings.
One example, is [Redis Cloud by Redis Labs](https://redislabs.com/redis-cloud)

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting one. If we go to basics of CAP Theorem and try to choose one DB based upon need of consistency, availability, and partition tolerance.

For High consistency and availability- Choose MySQL, PostgreSQL,Greenplum, Vertica, Neo4J.

For High availability and partition tolerance- Use Cassandra,Voldemort,Dynamo,CouchDB, Riak

For High consistency and partition tolerance- Use HBase, Redis, MongoDB,
BerkeleyDB, BigTable

**So my Vote is for Cassandra here.**

Comment: You didn't mention Couchbase. CouchDB is not Couchbase.